# How to select different rows in a table using Selenium?

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I have a table like this below
[image]
I have selected the rows which is there in yellow by pressing Ctrl or Shift Keys.
For selecting one row I use this xpath

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='webix_ss_center_scroll']//child::div[@column=0][@class='webix_column  webix_first']//child::div[@aria-colindex=1 and contains(., 28)]")
```

How do I select these multiple rows?
I am selecting 1 row based on index column

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: To select the highlighted rows you could use multiple predicates. Hard to tell without seeing the HTML code. Assuming `colindex` is used to select the rows, something like this should work (select rows n° 5,6,7,9,10,16,21) : `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='webix_ss_center_scroll']//div[@column=0][@class='webix_column  webix_first']//div[@aria-colindex=16 or @aria-colindex=21 or @aria-colindex>4 and @aria-colindex<11][not(@aria-colindex=8)][contains(.,28)]`